Ps3 super slim won't turn on after bending power supply pins
My ps3 ss was flickering on screen so someone suggested I open and clean it and apply thermal paste,that didn't work but I got a new problem. During the cleaning I accidentally bent the two power supply pins on the motherboard, I quickly straighten them back and closed it and it powered on. After playing for some few hours it went off. I checked everything again and now when you turn it on you hear one beep and it powers for like 3 seconds but if you hear 2 beeps it doesn't power at all. Could it be the bent pins or something else.
